# Rails: Grouping Hashes with same date and getting their difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

I have 2 hases:

`x = {Sun, 01 Oct 2017=>10, Wed, 01 Nov 2017=>4, Fri, 01 Dec 2017=>2}`

`y = {Sun, 01 Oct 2017=>7, Wed, 01 Nov 2017=>2, Fri, 01 Dec 2017=>1}`

I wanted to group them and get their difference, which should produce this result:

`z = {Sun, 01 Oct 2017=>3, Wed, 01 Nov 2017=>2, Fri, 01 Dec 2017=>1}`

Comment: Do you have any code you have tried, so we have a starting point?

Comment: This is where I got stuck, made a bunch of code to arrive at these two hashes.

Comment: I would suggest you look at how to iterate through a hash. With that, you should be able to see how to get the same item from the other hash and calculate yval - xval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to achieve this, as follows:

```
z = x.reduce({}) do |z_hash, (key, val)|
  next z_hash unless y[key]
  z_hash[key] = val - y[key]
  z_hash
end
```

Alternatively, and more built to purpose, you could use:

`z = x.merge(y) { |key, v1, v2| v1 - v2 }`

The first approach allows you to easily skip keys that don't appear in both hashes, while the second is what I'd recommend - [merge](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge) takes an optional block for cases like this.

It's readable and gets exactly the output you'd expect.

Hope that helps - give me a shout if you've any questions :)

Comment: The second one actually works perfectly. I don't want to disregard keys that don't have a match, it still has to be included in the merged hash. Thanks a lot for this. I also figured out another way just now, will post it as an answer but this one is much cleaner.

Comment: Glad to help out :) I've a bad habit of chucking `reduce` at everything as a first approach - much prefer to use the built-for-purpose methods, rather than re-inventing the wheel. Your approach below combines the two - `inject` is actually an alias of `reduce`. Nicely worked out :) Personally, of the options, I'd use the direct `merge` - it's clean, and likely performs a lot better than using `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

`ar = x , y
 z = p ar.inject{|memo, el| memo.merge( el ){|k, old_v, new_v| old_v - new_v}}`